# How to validate TextField with delay?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'd like to highlight EMAIL TextField as invalid not immediately but after 5 seconds user starts to type in.
So user types then stops then after 5 seconds validate the field and mark as invalid if error. I'm trying to use debouncing function but seems it's not working with TextField error property.
Is it the good approach?

```
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');

  export const emailHasError = (email) => {
    .... 
    return true; // if error
  }

  <TextField
    id="filled-basic"
    label="email"
    variant="filled"
    fullWidth
    error={email.length > 0 && debounce(emailHasError(email), 3000)}
    value={email}
    onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
  />
```

Comment: please add your `debounce` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your method, debounce will not return the value which you are returning from the inner function. debounce will return a timer so it will always true

I have added one more state to store the invalid value. and using the same debounce function onkeyUp.

```
 const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
 const [invalidEmail, setInvalidEmail] = useState(false)
 export const emailHasError = (email) => {
    .... 
    setInvalidEmail(true) // if error
  } 

  const checkEmail = () => {
   setInvalidEmail(false);
   debounce(emailHasError(email), 3000)
  }

  <TextField
    id="filled-basic"
    label="email"
    variant="filled"
    fullWidth
    error={invalidEmail}
    value={email}
    onKeyUp={checkEmail}
    onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
  />
```